# Change HTML content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am having two portions of code.

```html
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  $(".content" ).html('<div>My new div</div>');
}
```

```html
<p class="content">
  <a href="#">My link</a>
  <form>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</p>
```

The first one is supposed to place `<div>My new div</div>` before the tag `<a>` of the second code. But when I run it, all the content of the class `.content` is replaced by `<div>My new div</div>`. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Well when it doesn't do what you expect....it's not hard to look it up in the manual. At least do some basic research before asking here

Comment: surely putting a div, a link and a form inside of a <p> tag is poor code structure. P tags are meant to contain paragraphical content such as text - not be a container for every other tag in your code. Investigate the use of a div around the code, or use HTML semantic markup such as asides or sections. Anything but a P!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the .html() method, use .prepend()